# Variable List Comprehension Length

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm generating a list of lists via list comprehension, but I have no idea how to make the sub list's length variable by using a parameter. The input for the following is a tuple `(first, second)` and an `Integer` `z`:

`z` = 1:

```
[[a] | a <- [first..second]]
```

`z` = 2:

```
[[a, b] | a <- [first..second], b <- [first..second]]
```

`z` = 3:

```
[[a, b, c] | a <- [first..second], b <- [first..second], c <- [first..second]]
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what your end result is supposed to be... Can you give an example?

Comment: What about `replicateM z [first..second]` using `Control.Monad.replicateM`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `replicateM` for this task.  It's defined as

```
replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]
replicateM n m = sequence (replicate n m)
```

The connection here is to turn the list comprehension into `do` notation:

```
[[a] | a <- [first..second]] == do
    a <- [first..second]
    return [a]

[[a, b] | a <- [first..second], b <- [first..second]] == do
    a <- [first..second]
    b <- [first..second]
    return [a, b]

[[a, b, c] | a <- [first..second], b <- [first..second], c <- [first..second]] == do
    a <- [first..second]
    b <- [first..second]
    c <- [first..second]
    return [a, b, c]
```

To make it more clear, let's replace `[first..second]` by `m`:

```
do  let m = [first..second]
    a <- m
    b <- m
    c <- m
    return [a, b, c]
```

So here you can see that `m` is just getting replicated `n` times, hence `replicateM`.  Let's see how the types line up too:

```
replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]

m ~ []

replicateM_List :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

If you need to do this on arbitrary lists, not just repeating the same list, you can just use `sequence` on it

Comment: Awesome answer, as usual, and a good explanation of replicateM.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR use comprehension and a fold or go with bheklilr's replicateM suggestion

### Comprehension and a fold

You know what you're doing with list coprehension, so let's see how to do this recursively by first writing a function which prepends values of a list in all possible ways, so that

```
ghci> prepend "123" ["first","second"]
["1first","1second","2first","2second","3first","3second"]
```

```
prepend :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
prepend xs yss = [x:ys| x<-xs, ys<-yss]
```

Now let's make the list of lists, first using `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]` to replicate our list n times, then `prepend` each copy front of the others by folding the list:

```
lol :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
lol xs n = foldr prepend [[]] $ replicate n xs
```

```
ghci> lol "ab" 3
["aaa","aab","aba","abb","baa","bab","bba","bbb"]
ghci> lol [1..3] 2
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to use that with a pair `(start, finish)` as an argument.

### replicateM

As bheklilr points out in the comment, we can `import Control.Monad` and get

```
replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]
```

If you specialist that to lists, you get

```
replicateM :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

with that doing what you want:

```
ghci> replicateM 2 [1..3]
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

If, like me, you don't have as brilliant a mind as bheklilr,
you can use hoogle [like this](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[a]+-%3E+Int+-%3E+[[a]]) to search for functions with the type we need (`[a] -> Int -> [[a]]` in this case) and find that the third one down is `replicateM`. (`drop` and `take` don't do what we want.)

Comment: If you liked this, you should upvote bheklilr's [good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26444183/1598537) of how replicateM works, and why it's the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, both of you deserved it :)